# Dynamic Bulk Insert with duplicate record check

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Not sure where to begin on this one. I have routine that does bulk insert in a table, but once in a while I run into a duplicate record I get an error

I have two questions:

1. Does the bulk insert stop pushing in the remainder of records once a duplicate is found? OR does it keep going and finish all the records?
2. ONLY IF the routine stops at a duplicate:  then is there a way I can skip the record and continue forward?

Comment: Show the code of your routine and exact error you are getting.

Comment: If you have a unique index (on say a name) in your table, the bulk insert will fail on duplicate.  If you do not have such an index, the bulk insert will happily create duplicates. Note: at least your table definition would be helpful.

Comment: Can you enable the ignore duplicate Key index property?  It would require an index rebuild, but it would simple skip the duplicates when appropriate https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/03fd6976-ee4f-423a-ab74-7cf46091a693/avoid-insertion-of-duplicate-entries-in-a-bulk-insert-statement?forum=transactsql